# Github Actions script error in YAML syntax

Tags: github-actions

```
name: Test

on:
  workflow_call:
    secrets:
      MY_SECRET:
        required: true

jobs:
  shared-setup:
    uses: *****/*****/.github/workflows/shared-setup.yml@main

  unique-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: shared-setup

    env:
      SUPER_SECRET: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}

    - name: Do something
      run: echo "Hello World!"
```

I seem to have an errror in my YAML doc. but I can't see it. Deploying to GitHub results in an error that the document has an error in the yaml syntax near the line saying `unique-test:`.

Comment: What are those asterisks?

Comment: Remove those asterisks and add `steps` to your second job. See [here](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxNUMFqwzAMvfsrtDIoDJzcfRpsgV4Go+0YOxUn0Rpvjt1a1soo/fc5cT3qg8DvSU/vyekRFWyRohDeKQFw8uH70/rTrtPWTgAAYRcwUv4AvHzsNs3TutkWACDgkU3AXkEMjEJ8+XZup0EnVBJGPuRuJiQFy4fp1blWexMHbuuymerbsep3tI+jNm4pkgA7c2SUMRnOeoEdyeQcuGUXWVo9cTPlEPu061ZMzAS6n2J98/barEscuD+fS9jqPyVcLnmMIh6uR5Dg5sM9eyA/YhyM218VkyEF2A0eFiu01sO7D7a/W/wBFwpsnQ==).

Comment: See [`jobs.<job_id>.steps`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsteps) for more details.

Comment: @Azeem the aterisks are hiding my user/repo names. It's using a private workflow in the first step that is imported.

Comment: The Steps did solve it. No clue how I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `steps` in your second job i.e. `unique-test`.

I believe that in your first job, you deliberately redacted the username/repo for `uses`. Once the `steps` key is added and those asterisks are replaced with valid values, it should work fine.

Fixed workflow ([linted](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxNUE1rwzAMvftXaGVXJ3efCltgl8FoO8pOxUm0xpsjp5a1Mkr/+5ykGb0Y/J70PkS2RwM75KRUIKMAziF+f/pwPjTW+xEAYGwiJp4/AK8fh231tKl2CwAQ8SQuYmsgRUGlvkI9jXNnM6oZkwzztDCyGd9I2bqMOISyOLrUSV0u1lze7xW/vV/31pHKAkLuJKhTDjzrRSHWOTlILZREeztyE0WIbfa611ITgfSzRN++v1WbpQ48Xi5L2eK/JVyv8xonHG5H0EDT4Z4DcOgxdY6ON8UcyAA2XYDVC3ofYB+ibx9Wf/bbb8E=)):

```yaml
name: Test

on:
  workflow_call:
    secrets:
      MY_SECRET:
        required: true

jobs:
  shared-setup:
    uses: username/repo/.github/workflows/shared-setup.yml@main

  unique-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: shared-setup

    env:
      SUPER_SECRET: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}

    steps:
    - name: Do something
      run: echo "Hello World!"
```

- Always use https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint to lint your workflows.
- Also, you can use https://github.com/nektos/act to lint as well run your workflows locally.

Answer (score 0):

you can use online tool like [yaml checker](https://yamlchecker.com/) or editor in the github workflow it self. and it's quite helpful.

1. the `uses` of `shared-setup` should be in string, you can use ``` `` ``` | `''`
2. you have to put the process below `steps`,

the result should be like:

```
name: Test

on:
  workflow_call:
    secrets:
      MY_SECRET:
        required: true

jobs:
  shared-setup:
    uses: '*****/*****/.github/workflows/shared-setup.yml@main'

  unique-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: shared-setup    
    steps:
      - name: Do something
        run: echo "Hello World!"
        env:
          SUPER_SECRET: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}
```

Comment: Even though the YAML in your answer is valid, it is not valid GHA workflow. See [here](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxNkE1rwzAMhu/6FVrZNcndp8IW2GUw2o6yU3ESrfHmyKllrYzS/z6nIaMXgV59vI/EdiCDO5IEENgA4jnE708fzofWej8JiEJtpCRzgvj6cdjWT5t6twiIkU7qInUGU1QC+ArNrV16m9VCKOk4d6uQmClGztZVpDFU5dGlXptqsZbqfq78Hfx6sI4BlN1JqUgZ10BUliIzozbKSQtvJx2YqMsO9xsmX5BEY2YqkG8nPweUMFDqHR8zWF5mkNo+4OqFvA+4D9F3D6tcIv6Z0bfvb/VmOR0fL5flMeX/R/B6hT/7rmz3).

Comment: @Azeem because you put `bad indentation` on your code. and i only took a part of his code. i also have tried it in your link, it `works` as expected

Comment: i updated my answer with full code.

Comment: I linted the workflow that you posted in your original answer (see [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75572595/1)) and I did not indent it at all. Anyways, it's fine now.